# How to create popup in lightning web component

Tags: javascript, html, css, salesforce, lwc

Page which will display New Milestone popup in the org, there should be one button for Add new milestone. On click of this button, popup will ask for milestone details and after click on save button this new milestone details will add to DB.

Milestone is a custom object.

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Save Function is not working

Comment: So... you want to know how to make a save function? How to make a pop-up? Why the save function is not working? How to add a Button?.... Did you read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - I have the feeling you really should (re)read it. We can't read your mind. We can only work with the information you posted.

Comment: Did you read [Create Lightning Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_introduction) from official docs?

Answer (score 1):

Create lwc component target for lightning__RecordAction.
You can place your your code there.

If Save is not working, feel free the paste your error message, we can help better ?

If you want to make your custom popup, see below link
https://www.infallibletechie.com/2020/03/popup-using-lightning-web-component-lwc.html